# Duplicate the categories of product

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to copy the `categories` pivot for the product where `id=15` and apply it to another product. Is there any shorthand to do the copy paste instead of getting the array and attach loop through?

```php
$product = App\Product::find(15);   
$product->categories()->attach([1, 5]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$product = App\Product::find(15);
$newProduct = $product->replicate();
$newProduct->save();
```

and for the relations

```
$newProduct->categories()->attach($product->categories);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well your nee you want to attach the same categories which are attached to product with `id = 15` to another product.

```
$product = App\Product::find(15);
```

After getting the concern product I can get `Array` of **ids** of categories to which that product is belongs to by calling `pluck` on collection of categories attached to that product

```
$categories_id = $product->categories()->pluck('id'); // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

If the second product on which I want to attach that categories has `id = 5` I can perform the replication like this

```
$otherProduct = App\Product::find(5);

$otherProduct->categories()->sync($categories_id);
```